# Losing connection to Qlik Sense app after 3 minutes (Websockets & C#)

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, websocket, qliksense

I currently have a connection to qlik that is based on websockets and JSON, that is run through a C# script in the Unity engine.
It works perfectly fine to begin with, but after roughly 3 minutes, the connection is lost and I get an ObjectDisposedException which makes me unable to recieve Qlik messages.

Part of the exception:

> ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name:
>   'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'. System.Net.WebConnection.Read
>   (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request, System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32
>   offset, System.Int32 size) (at :0)
>   System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket+c__AnonStorey5.<>m__0
>   () (at :0)

My method for recieving messages form Qlik:

```
private static async void ReceiveWs(ClientWebSocket ws)
    {
        // Keep listening while socket is open
        while (ws.State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            // Receive in chunks through byte array
            WebSocketReceiveResult incoming;
            String resultString = "";
            do
            {
                Byte[] bufferByte = new byte[1024];
                incoming = await ws.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(bufferByte), CancellationToken.None);
                resultString += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bufferByte).TrimEnd('\0');
            }
            while (!incoming.EndOfMessage);

             ...

        }
    }
```

I think the problem originates in this code, but I am not quite sure. I can provide more code if you think it is needed. Any help is appreciated!
/Erik

Comment: Where you dispose `ws`?

Comment: @Gusman I don't ever actually dispose it. But I do call `ws.CloseOutputAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Done", CancellationToken.None);` upon application quit.

Comment: you might be reaching the session timeout if your script is not interacting with the engine. I think somewhere in the virtual proxy settings (in QMC) was able to change the timeout

Comment: @StefanStoichev I am relatively new to Qlik, so I do not really know what I am talking about. But I am currently connecting to the desktop application, so QMC should not be a possibility right now (I think).